# Way to pass "this" instance of a module

Tags: ocaml

Using mirage, I have a pretty big functor mess. Trying to clean it up a bit, I've made a big ugly `Context` module parametrized over all the types and values I need to pass around in my code. Since apparently passing only the values I need would allow types to "escape their scope" to quote the compiler, I just end up passing that module around as an argument to functions 
`fun x (module Ctx : Context) ... =`

A bit annoying to use but it works.
So basically :

```
let module Context = MkContext(S)(C)(ContextConfig) in
S.listen_tcpv4 stackv4 ~port:8442 (Context.handleConnection console);
```

From inside Context.handleConnection, I need to call a function which takes the Context as an argument. One way to do that I guess would be to pass Context to handleConnection, like this :

```
S.listen_tcpv4 stackv4 ~port:8442 (Context.handleConnection console (module Context));
```

and then pass that around from handleConnection as a this to the functions needing that, but I imagine there must be a better way ?

EDIT : Can't even do that, I would need to module type to be recursive, which doesn't seem trivial.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] to illustrate the problem? That would make the question and subsequent answers much more clear, and makes it easier for us non-gurus to fiddle around and stumble upon something that works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is a good idea , but it is possible to define recursive module types through recursive modules:

```
module rec R: sig 
  module type S = sig
    val f: (module R.S) -> int -> int
  end
 end = R
```

We are using here the trick that type-level components are added during the recursive module expansion to avoid some repetitions. Without this trick, it is probably better to start defining the inner module type with a placeholder `self` type

```
   module type I = sig
     type self
     val f: self -> int -> int
   end
```

Then, we can remove the placeholder type during the recursive definition:

```
  module rec R : sig
    module type S = I with type self := (module R.S)
  end = struct
    module type S = I with type self := (module R.S)
  end
```

Finally, we can use the recursive module type with

```
module X = struct
    let f (module Self: R.S) n =
      if n = 0 then 1 else n * Self.f (module Self) (n-1)
end
let six = X.f (module X) 3
```